# How can I get user links in the API call like Twitter, GitHub and so on?

Tags: support, api, users, hyperlinks

I'm trying to get the user's user links from his profile. Like [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon)
has GitHub and Twitter links on his profile. How can I get those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API only returns the website link (jarroddixon.com), not the Twitter and GitHub usernames. You can check the results [here](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/3?site=stackoverflow). The same holds for the [Users table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/295232) in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com), so that's not an option either.

I think the best way is just to 'scrape' the user's profile page (which is public, so you don't need to be logged in to view it), parse the HTML and look for `<a>` elements with the attribute `rel=me`.