# Where do I get the user impact?

Tags: support, api, users

I'm trying to get the data of the user's *impact*.
[image: User Impact]

Therefore I used the [/2.2/me](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me) route and did not found any of this data.
Is there any other route that gives this information?

I'm also missing the information about the *Twitter name* or *GitHub name* that are visible on the user account.

Comment: It turns out I've answered a similar question before: [How can I get user links in the API call like Twitter, GitHub and so on?](https://stackapps.com/q/7549/34061)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those fields are not exposed on the [user](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) object. They are not in SEDE either, according to the [schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede). I think those fields have been added after the API was created, and they simply didn't bother to update.

The alternative, if you keep the number of requests low, is to scrape each user's profile page. Take care that anonymous requests open user profiles by default on the [Profile tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11823079/norbert-bartko?tab=profile), instead of the [Activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11823079/norbert-bartko?tab=activity) which is opened when you view your own profile.